# Best way to mount an image in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, iso-image, bin-cue-image

What is the best way to mount an image in Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: See also [Freeware ISO mount software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7211/2210) on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[virtual clone drive](https://forum.redfox.bz/forums/virtual-clonedrive.21/), howto is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: beat me to it.  :)

Comment: Virtual Clone Drive works fine for me indeed

Comment: WinCDEmu blows it out of the water.

Comment: I agree. I just tried WinCDEmu after being a long time user of PowerISO and DAEMON Tools.  There is no comparison, it just does what it does without fuss.  Perfect.  No waste, no mess.  Use WinCDEmu.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: @PeterMortensen fixed.

Answer (score 10):

OK, there's a lot of them out there and I've tried them all.  [WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) is completely seamless within the Windows Explorer environment.  Want to mount an image?  Just right click on the file and select a drive letter and it's done.  You can install it as a driver or you can just use the standalone version.  This is by far the best one other there and best of all, it's free!

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of portable apps that don't need to be installed and leave virtually no footprint. [WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/portable/) is an open source, portable app that works in Windows 7 64 bit (that's what I'm running). I like it because it only temporarily "installs" its drivers when you actually launch the app, so there's no additional overhead when the software is not being used.

It doesn't have the windows Explorer or context menu bells and whistles that some of the other offerings have, and it could really benefit from a drag-and-drop update. But other than the minor inconvenience of having to go through a file dialog to mount your images, it works great.

Answer (score 3):

[DAEMON Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/news/04cb4a55de28fab2b3d57fc214fdb0b5)
is freeware and is said to work on Windows Vista x64, so it will also work on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: i was surprised when I read that it is bundled with spyware. link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @ragu.pattabi: All one has to do is decline the offer of this additional software. DAEMON Tools Lite will still work fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Daemon Tools Pro](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/news/04cb4a55de28fab2b3d57fc214fdb0b5) claims full Win7 support in its latest version.  This is the paid version of Daemon Tools.

[Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) also claims full support ([HOWTO](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/) link from akira's post).

Comment: The second link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[Alcohol 52%](http://www.free-downloads.net/programs/Alcohol_52__Free_Edition) (free) or Alcohol 120% if you want the paid-for bells & whistles...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Power ISO 4.5](http://www.poweriso.com/)

It's easier than Daemon Tools or any virtual drive software.